# how to calculate different groups of one million binary sequences?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, cluster-computing

I have one million binary sequences ,they are in the same length, such as (1000010011,1100110000....) and so on. And I want to know how many different groups they have(same sequences belong to same group ).what is the fastest way?
No stoi please.

Comment: First, what is your way?

Comment: a binary tree of the same depth or a cluster algorithm

Comment: You can try both solutions and do some benchmarking to find out which is the fastest way.

Answer (score 1):

#### Depending on the length L of a sequence:

**L < ~20: bucket sort**
This is short enough in comparison to the input size. A bucketsort with L buckets is all you need. - preallocate an array of size 2<sup>L</sup>, since you have ~million sequences and 2<sup>20</sup> is ~million, you will only need O(n) of additional memory.

- Go through your sequence, sort to the buckets
- Go through the buckets, count the results. Return them.
- And we're done.

The time complexity will be O(n) with O(n) memory cost. This is optimal complexity-wise since you have to visit every element at least once to check its value anyway.

**L reasonably large: hash table**
If you pick a reasonable hashing function and a good size of the hash table(or a dictionary if we need to store the counts)<sup>1</sup> you will have small number of collisions while inserting. The amortized time will be O(n) since if the hash is good, then the insert is amortized O(1).
As a side note, the bucket sort is technically a perfect hash since the hash function in this case is an one-to-one function.

**L unreasonably large: binary tree**
if for some reason the construction of hash is not feasible or you wish for consistency then building a binary tree to hold the values is a way to go.
This will take O(nlog(n)) as binary trees usually do.

---

<sup>1</sup> ~2M should be enough and it is still O(n). Maybe you could go even lower to around 1,5M size.